# How can solve this differential equation (third equation )?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

How can I solve this differential equation?

$$
 \frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{\frac{A}{y}+\frac{B}{y^2}+\frac{C}{y^4}+\frac{D}{y^5}+\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{y}+\frac{3}{y^2})^2}}
$$

where $A,B,C,D$ are constants.

Comment: Where is this nighmare coming from ? In any manner, I should look for the integration of $dx/dy$ with respect to $y$ but with no big hope (except for very specific values of $A,B,C,D$, ...may be)

Comment: yes really its nightmare :(

Comment: @user3234456.At least, we reached an agreement on something !

Comment: Claude Leibovici yes that is :(

Comment: Its not a nightmate. On the contrary its so restful to just answer : use numerical methods to solve it !

Comment: yes my second choice is numerical way , but i want try first choice if possible to walk on it